# JQuery AppendGrid with MVC4 controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, grid

How do we integrate an AppendGrid control in a Visual studio MVC4 solution?

The problem is that I can't use  @Html.EditorFor because the appendgrid control is constructed automatically.

In the following attempt, filter is always empty.

I guess that there could be 2 solutions.

1. Manage to pass a serialized string containing the grid to the controller ( what I tried to do but does not work yet)
   or
2. use standard Html.BeginForm @Html.EditorFor technique

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewFilter(string filter)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


@model Models.FilterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Filter";
}

<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Filter</legend>
    <table id="tblAppendGrid"></table>  
 </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialize appendGrid
    $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
        caption: 'Filters Collections',
        initRows: 4,
        columns: [
            { name: 'AttributeName', display: 'Attribute Name', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '160px'} },
            { name: 'Operation', display: 'Operation', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: { 0: 'Choose', 1: 'Equals', 2: 'DoesNotEqual', 3: 'Contains', 4: 'DoesNotContain', 5: 'StartsWith', 6: 'DoesNotStartWith', 7: 'MatchRegex', 8: 'DoesNotMatchRegex' }, ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100px'} },
            { name: 'AttributeValue', display: 'Attribute Value', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 4 }, ctrlCss: { width: '160px'} }
        ],

        hideButtons: {
            moveUp: true,
            moveDown: true
        }
    });
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dialog_Save-button').button().click(function () {
    var oData = $(document.forms[0]).serialize()
 alert(oData);
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: "/configuration/NewFilter",
     data: oData,
     success: alert("Record UdpateSucessfully.")
 });
 });
</script>
```